# serialize verbose fields of related foreign key object in django REST?

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework

for an app with three objects - `User`, `Event`, and `Action` where users take actions on events creating an object like:

```
class Action(models.Model):
    event = models.ForeignKey('CauseActivity', on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='actions')
    user = models.ForeignKey('users.User', on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='actions')
    type = models.CharField(max_length=100, choices=ACTION_TYPES)
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    date_updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

I would like our RESTful API to be able to return the actions for one specific user, either within the user request (which requires no extra API calls) or with one additional request (get actions by user)

a simple User serializer with 'actions' as a field will return only the obj ids (response to GET ex: `"actions":[108,109]`)

```
from rest_framework import serializers

class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = (
            ..., 'actions', )
```

I am aware of nesting to serialize custom fields like `username = serializers.ReadOnlyField(source='user.name')` but is there a way to use serializers.ListSerializer or .ModelSerializer to serialize the full set of `Action` objects' fields within my `UserSerializer`? I read through https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/ and best approach isn't really clear to me. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

create a serializer for your `Action` model (let's call it `ActionSerializer`) then make your code like

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    actions = ActionSerializer(many=True)
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('actions',...)
```